# CI3.0 passing variable between controller and module

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I have this method:

```
public function signup_validation()   {
//definizioni setting per email di conferma
  $emailsetting = array('mailtype' => 'html' );
  $emailfrom = 'misure@lagiumentabardata.netsons.org';
  $emailsubject ='Conferma registrazione';

$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]'); //check se la mail è davvero una mail valida e se esiste gia nel database     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');   $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Conferma Password','required|trim|matches[password]');

$this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique','email già esistente nel nostro database'); //override messaggio di errore

//check se il form è valido allora passa altrimenti ritorna al form.    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
    //generare key
  $key = sha1(uniqid());
  //inviare una mail all'utente
  $this->load->library('email', $emailsetting); //caricamento libreria
  $this->load->model('model_users'); //caricamento modello per il controllo del db utente

  $this->email->from($emailfrom,'La Giumenta Bardata');
  $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));
  $this->email->subject($emailsubject);

  $emailmessage = "<h1>ciao mondo</h1>
                  <a href='".base_url()."signup/register_user/$key'>click qui</a>"; //fare riferimento alla funzione register_user

  $this->email->message($emailmessage);

  //controllo scrittura dell'utente nel db
  if ($this->model_users->add_temp_user($key) == true) { //passaggio chiave al modello che si occupa di aggiungerlo al DB
    //invio email utente
    if ($this->email->send() == true) {
      echo "email inviata correttamente";
    } else { echo "errore nell'invio stronzo";}
  } else { echo "problemi nell'inserimento del db"; }

} else {
    echo '<script>alert("TU NON PUOI PASSARE!");</script>';
    $this->registrazione();     }   }
```

In a `signup.php` controller.
First of all I don't understand why if I move `$emailmessage` variable where I set all the variables (`$emailsetting`, `$emailfrom` etc.) I get an error that the `$emailmessage` variable is undefined -.-

but, the real problem is that i can't pass the `$key` variable to a module:

```
 public function add_temp_user($key){

 $data = array('email' => $this->input->post('email'),
               'nome' => $this->input->post('nome'),
               'cognome' => $this->input->post('cognome'),
               'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
               'userkey'=>$key
               );

  $query = $this->db->insert('temp_users',$data);  //generazione query

  //check se la query è stata eseguita correttamente
  if ($query) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }   
 }
```

How can I pass a variable from a controller to a module? I try everything, from set the `$key` as public to set the `__construct` and nothing work...when the app needs to call the model I have an Undefined `$key` variable..

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You can move `$emailmessage =` up where the other things are set. But the line `$key = sha1(uniqid());` must come before those assignments.

I tested this as best I could without having your database. Seems to work. `$key` makes it to the model anyway.

Notice that I build the link `<a href=...` a little differently, making better use of Codeigniter's abilities.

```
 public function signup_validation()
  {
    //generare key
    $key = sha1(uniqid());
//definizioni setting per email di conferma
    $emailsetting = array('mailtype' => 'html');
    $emailfrom = 'misure@lagiumentabardata.netsons.org';
    $emailsubject = 'Conferma registrazione';
    $emailmessage = "<h1>ciao mondo</h1>
      <a href='".base_url("signup/register_user/$key")."'>click qui</a>"; //fare riferimento alla funzione register_user

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]'); //check se la mail è davvero una mail valida e se esiste gia nel database     $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');   $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','Conferma Password','required|trim|matches[password]');

    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'email già esistente nel nostro database'); //override messaggio di errore
//check se il form è valido allora passa altrimenti ritorna al form.    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
    //inviare una mail all'utente
    $this->load->library('email', $emailsetting); //caricamento libreria
    $this->load->model('model_users'); //caricamento modello per il controllo del db utente

    //use chaining here, much more efficient
    $this->email
        ->from($emailfrom, 'La Giumenta Bardata')
        ->to($this->input->post('email'))
        ->subject($emailsubject)
        ->message($emailmessage);

    //controllo scrittura dell'utente nel db
    if($this->model_users->add_temp_user($key))
    { //passaggio chiave al modello che si occupa di aggiungerlo al DB
      //invio email utente
      if($this->email->send() == true)
      {
        echo "email inviata correttamente";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "errore nell'invio stronzo";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      echo "problemi nell'inserimento del db";
    }
//these lines are not connected to anything as you have them in your question. 
// So I have commented them out
//else {
//    echo '<script>alert("TU NON PUOI PASSARE!");</script>';
//    $this->registrazione();     }   
  }
```

Here's the model function.

I capture the inputs like this `input->post(NULL, TRUE);` because it grabs all the inputs at once. That eliminates multiple calls to `input->`. With the second argument=TRUE the inputs are sanitized.

Because `db->insert()` returns either true or false there is no need for the if/then statement.

```
  public function add_temp_user($key)
  {
    $posted = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    $data = array('email' => $posted('email'),
        'nome' => $posted('nome'),
        'cognome' => $posted('cognome'),
        'password' => md5($posted('password')),
        'userkey' => $key
    );
    //tornare successo o il fallimento di ricerca
    return $this->db->insert('temp_users', $data);  //generazione query
  }
```